# Kendo Grid only shows drop down when clicked on

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with multiple columns.  One of the columns is defined with an EditorTemplateName and that template is a dropdown list.  The name of the grid is BulkParcelStatusUpdateGrid and the name of the EditorTempate is DropDownEditor.cshtml.

This is the code that generates the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.ParcelBulkUpdateViewModel>()
    .Name("BulkParcelStatusUpdateGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelKey).Title("Parcel Key").Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.LotNo).Title("Lot #").Width(50);
        columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.AssembledTaxDescription).Title("Tax Description").Width(140);
        columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelStatus).Title("Current Status").Width(140);
        columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelBulkStatusUpdate)
               .Title("New Status")
               .Width(150)
               .EditorTemplateName("DropDownEditor");

        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                 .Ajax()
                 .Batch(true)
                 .ServerOperation(false)
                 .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                 .Model(model =>
                 {
                      model.Id(n => n.ParcelKey);
                      model.Field(n => n.LotNo).Editable(false);
                      model.Field(n => n.AssembledTaxDescription).Editable(false);
                      model.Field(n => n.ParcelStatus).Editable(false);
                      model.Field(n => n.ParcelBulkStatusUpdate).Editable(true);
                 })
                 .PageSize(20)
                 .Read(read => { read.Action("GetDetailedParcelDetails", "Parcel").Data("{ CaseKey: " + @Model.CaseKey + "}"); }))
        )
```

This is the code in the editor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .BindTo(ViewBag.ParcelStatusList)
    .Name("NewParcelStatus")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
  )
```

When the grid is rendered, the drop down is not there.  When I click in the grid box where the drop down should be, it appears.  I can select a value in the dropdown but when I click on the drop down in row 2, the drop down in row 1 disappears.

How can I set this up so the drop downs in all rows are always rendered and shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior with InCell edit mode - the editor is rendered only when the cell enters edit mode.

If you need the editor visible at all time you will need to:

- use a ClientTemplate to render the desired component
- prevent the cells in the column from entering edit mode
- when the value in the ClientTemplate editor is updated manually update the underlying model

Keep in mind that if you have excessive number of editors rendered via ClientTemplates there might be [performance penalties](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/performance/common-mistakes)

Here are two basic examples using a checkbox as an editor:

- https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/cROUHaYh05l9Xccw48 - The ClientTemplate renders an input that is styled as a checkbox and the change of state is intercepted to update the underlying model
- https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mdOgHYEh07HK6Lvp43 - this one relies on the [MVVM pattern](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview) and renders a component in the ClientTemplate:

  ```
  columns.Bound(p => p.Discontinued).Editable("returnFalse")
   .ClientTemplate(
       Html.Kendo().CheckBox()
           .Name("cbx#=ProductID#")
           .HtmlAttributes(new{data_bind="value: Discontinued"})
           .ToClientTemplate().Value
       ).Width(100);
  ```

The data_bind attribute added specifies the MVVM binding for the field. This ensures the underlying model is updated when a change occurs. The returnFalse function does just that - returns false, so no default editor is generated when the user clicks on a cell. You will need to add a DataBound event handler to bind the component to the actual model:

```
.Events(ev=>ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
 
 <script>
    function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = this;
        grid.table.find("tr").each(function () {
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);

            $(this).find('script').each(function () {
                eval($(this).html());
            });

            kendo.bind($(this), dataItem);
        });
    }
  </script>
```

The approach for a DropDownList would be the same.